# Double Validation Error, How to fix?

Tags: python

```
`import time
WarriorSpellOne, WarriorSpellTwo, WarriorSpellThree, WarriorSpellUltimite =  ("Slash"), ("Hammer Down"), ("Flame Strike"), ("Ragnarok")
MageSpellOne, MageSpellTwo, MageSpellThree, MageSpellUltimite = ("Fireball"), ("Lightning Strike"), ("Necromancy"), ("Mutation")
ArcherSpellOne, ArcherSpellTwo, ArcherSpellThree, ArcherSpellUltimite = ("Tri-Shot"), ("Aimed Shot"), ("Snare"), ("Arrow Rain")
RougeSpellOne, RougeSpellTwo, RougeSpellThree, RougeSpellUltimite = ("Backstab"), ("Smoke Bomb"), ("Blade Toss"), ("Shadow Wars")
SpellOne, SpellTwo, SpellThree, SpellUltimite = ("N/A"), ("N/A"), ("N/A"), ("N/A")
WarriorHealth, WarriorAttack, WarriorMana = int(200), int(10), int(100)
MageHealth, MageAttack, MageMana = int(75), int(10), int(200)
ArcherHealth, ArcherAttack, ArcherMana = int(150), int(15), int(150)
RougeHealth, RougeAttack, RougeMana = int(100), int(20), int(50)
ClassHealth, ClassAttack, ClassMana = int(0), int(0), int(0)
ClassSelected = ("N/A")
Class = int(0)
Confirm = int(0)
 try:
    Class = int(input("\nSelect a class, Warrior(1), Mage(2), Archer(3), Rouge(4)"))
    while Confirm != 1:
        while Class <= 4 and Class >= 1 :   
            if Class == 1:
                ClassHealth, ClassAttack, ClassMana = WarriorHealth, WarriorAttack, WarriorMana
                SpellOne, SpellTwo, SpellThree, SpellUltimite = WarriorSpellOne, WarriorSpellTwo, WarriorSpellThree, WarriorSpellUltimite
                ClassSelected = ("Warrior")                
            if Class == 2:
                ClassHealth, ClassAttack, ClassMana = MageHealth, MageAttack, MageMana
                SpellOne, SpellTwo, SpellThree, SpellUltimite = MageSpellOne, MageSpellTwo, MageSpellThree, MageSpellUltimite
                ClassSelected = ("Mage")
            if Class == 3:
                ClassHealth, ClassAttack, ClassMana = ArcherHealth, ArcherAttack, ArcherMana
                SpellOne, SpellTwo, SpellThree, SpellUltimite = ArcherSpellOne, ArcherSpellTwo, ArcherSpellThree
                ClassSelected = ("Archer")
            if Class == 4:
                ClassHealth, ClassAttack, ClassMana = RougeHealth, RougeAttack, RougeMana
                SpellOne, SpellTwo, SpellThree, SpellUltimite = RougeSpellOne, RougeSpellTwo, RougeSpellThree, RougeSpellUltimite
                ClassSelected = ("Rouge")
            print ("\nYou have selected the {} class. {} Health, {} Attack, {} Mana".format(ClassSelected, ClassHealth, ClassAttack, ClassMana))
            print ("\nYour spells are; {}, {}, {} and {}".format(SpellOne, SpellTwo, SpellThree, SpellUltimite))
            time.sleep(3)
            Confirm = int(input("\nDo you want to continue with this class? Yes(1), No(0)"))
            if Confirm == 0:
                ClassHealth, ClassAttack, ClassMana, SpellOne, SpellTwo, SpellThree, SpellUltimite = int(0), int(0), int(0), ("N/A"), ("N/A"), ("N/A"), ("N/A")
except (ValueError, TypeError):
    Class = int(input("\nInvalid Class, try again | Warrior(1), Mage(2), Archer(3), Rouge(4)"))`
```

I'm trying to make my own game for fun, this is the class selection stage
The validation is not working though, When using IDLE, if a number outside the range e.g. 5 is input-ed, nothing happens. As well as when I enter a character, it will say the error phrase, however when I re-enter the same character it will crash the programme.

Any suggestions to improve the validation? I'm also new to python so my knowledge of code is lacking a bit

**EDIT**
Working on it, Just leaving it open as a bookmark, but no need for new answers

Comment: Just FYI here, but your data structure (or lack thereof) is going to give you nothing but trouble. Games are an ideal use case for [objects](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/classes.html). Also, integers like `20` are already integers. You don't have to cast them with `int(20)`. And `Rouge` is a cosmetics product (you're looking for `Rogue`).

Comment: One thing that could really help you: organization!

Comment: After (and only **after**) you get this doing what you want it to do, please take it over to http://codereview.stackexchange.com!

Comment: @leekaiinthesky May i ask why? I might result to a different approach to this code by changing its initial purpose, but what is the purpose for taking it to the code review website? (friendly question, no hostility :D )

Comment: The Code Review Stack Exchange is for people to post working code and to have the community make suggestions about how to make it better (conforming more to programming best practices in general). The people who commented before me suggested that you need better organization and a custom data structure. These suggestions don't directly address the question you've posted here and may not even change how your code operates. However, they will make your code better, easier to read, and easier to write, and they are exactly what the Code Review community is intended to address.

Comment: The reason I stressed "after" is that the Code Review community likes improving code that already does what the asker wants. They don't want to be solving questions about making it do what you want, if it doesn't already do it. (Stack Overflow *is* the right place for that. By the way, welcome to Stack Overflow!)

Comment: Thanks :) I think i'll just make another code with similar purpose then post it on the codereview website, thanks for the recommendation btw :)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is only triggered if an exception is thrown. For example, if the user inputs `"hello"`, and you call `int("hello")` this will throw a `ValueError` and trigger the error message.

However, if you call `int("5")`, there is no error here – it just returns 5. Then the code enters the outer `while` loop, but it doesn't enter the inner `while` loop (because 5 is not <= 4). So it just sits in the outer loop forever. It will never throw an exception or leave the loop.

You can handle the case when `Class` is a number but doesn't fall between 1 and 4 just after the inner `while` loop, if you want.

**Update:**

Try something like this:

```
# Here's a method that will check whether the input is ok
def isValidCharacterClassInput(userInput):
    try:
        # Return True if the input is between 1 and 4
        # Return False if the input is an integer that doesn't fall within this range
        return 1 <= int(userInput) and int(userInput) <= 4
    # ValueError exception gets thrown if the input couldn't be turned into an int, for example, if the input is "2.5" or "hello"
    except ValueError:
        # In this case, also return False
        return False

# Get input from the user
characterClassInput = input("Input 1, 2, 3 or 4: ")

# If the input is ok, skip this part
# If the input is not ok, enter the loop and ask for input again
while not isValidCharacterClassInput(characterClassInput):
    print "You have not chosen a valid number. Please try again."
    characterClassInput = input("Input 1, 2, 3 or 4: ")

# We don't get here until the input is validated
print "You have chosen", characterClassInput
```

Comment: I didn't fully understand your explanation, could you provide some sort of short code to demonstrate what i did wrong and how to fix it please?

Comment: I added some code for validating the input. Hope that helps!

Comment: What is 'def' ? I want to try to keep my code to a point where i can understand it a bit because i am a student still in high school. But i see that 'def' in most of the questions that i search, what relevance does it have?

Comment: `def` is how to define functions in Python. Defining your own functions, methods, and object classes is one of the most powerful parts of any programming language. You can read about how to define Python functions with `def` here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions. In fact, you could read through the entire tutorial here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html. (I've linked you to the Python 2 tutorial. If you're using Python 3, there's a Python 3 tutorial too, but at this stage, it shouldn't much matter which version of Python you're using.)

Comment: I strongly recommend working through the tutorial. If you're really just starting out, Stack Overflow just isn't going to be able to help as much as learning the foundations first. Good luck, and welcome to the wonderful world of computer programming!

Comment: I shall go through it, thanks for the warm welcome :D

Comment: Last comment for me, could i have a link to the tutorial please? i clearly have a lot to learn in this wonderful world

Comment: The links are in my previous comment. Do you see them?